# Reset button does not work after validation errors

Tags: jsf, primefaces, reset

I have a Form to add a new user. I am using Validator messages to control empty fields. If I enter invalid data and submit the form, error messages were displayed. After that I click on reset button, it doesn't work.
This my code in html:

```
<h:form id="newCustomerForm">
    <p:dialog draggable="true"  header="New Customer" widgetVar="customerDialogNew" resizable="false"  
                      showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" style="position: absolute ;"  id="dialog2">  
        <p:panelGrid id="newCustomer" columns="6" >  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <p:graphicImage value="../../pictures/customerAdd.jpg"/>  
            </f:facet>  
            <p:outputLabel value="Name:" for="name" />
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{customerMB.name}" title="Name" required="true" requiredMessage="The Name field is required."/>
            <p:message for="name" />
            <p:outputLabel value="FamilyName:" for="familyName" />
            <p:inputText id="familyName" value="#{customerMB.familyName}" title="FamilyName" required="true" requiredMessage="The FamilyName field is required."/>
            <p:message for="familyName" />
        </p:panelGrid> 
        <p:commandButton type="reset" immediate="true" update="newCustomerForm" value="Clear" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n" styleClass="ui-priority-primary">
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton value="Save" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-circle-check" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" action="#{customerMB.addCustomer()}" /> 
    </p:dialog>  
</h:form>
```

Comment: Could you try `ajax="false"` on your reset button? And remove the update. You are not using any bean method to clear the fields here, but standard browser functionality.

Comment: I Added ajax="false" and removed the update but still have the same problem; last datas inserted before validation errors still appear and clear doesn't work :( `<p:commandButton type="reset" immediate="true" ajax="false" value="Clear" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n" styleClass="ui-priority-primary">
                    </p:commandButton>`